# receive an incoming SIP call with vidyo.io mediaBridge

Tags: sip, vidyo

I am trying to configure a vidyo.io docker mediaBridge instance to receive sip calls. To do that I am leaving the field *destination* empty in the /opt/vidyo/config file. I am following the other steps in the documentation like definining mediaports, and publicIp and creating the instance with the port mapping

```
docker run -d --name sipCall -p 50000-50100:50000-50100/udp -p 5060:5060/udp vidyo/mediabridge
```

however this does not seems to do anything, nothing is running, and there are not ports listening in the docker instance. gw.log shows that call was terminated after few seconds.

Config file is something like this

```
width=1280
height=720
fps=30
kbps=2000
layout=1
maxParticipants=8
overlay=1
videoCodec=H264
audioCodec=PCM
maxCallDuration=180   # duration in minutes
#Presentation settings
presentationAllowed=1 #0 - ignore presentations 1 - replace main video with presentation
presWidth=1280
presHeight=720
presFps=5
presKbps=300
destination=""
mediaPorts="50000-50100"
samplingRate=16000
publicIp="1.2.3.4"
resourceId="test"
token="XXXX"
host="prod.vidyo.io"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case this saves time to someone else, at the end, after contacting technical support It does not seems that receiving SIP calls is supported out of the box by vidyo.io

It migh be possible to do via some sip proxy, but definelty not a simple step.